# using data retrieved from firebase repositry outside of function in Kotlin

Tags: android, arrays, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I take the base64 data type image from firebase and assign it to the "decoded_card2" variable as a bitmap. However, I cannot use this variable outside of the "fromFirebase_card2.get()" function I created. How can I do that ?

NOTE: My goal is to create a bitmap array of images like this one and shuffle all of them.

```
val fromFirebase_card2 = collection_cards.document("albus")
fromFirebase_card2.get()
    .addOnSuccessListener{ document ->

        var Cards_b64 = document.data!!["image"].toString()
        var Cards_bytes = Base64.decode(Cards_b64, Base64.DEFAULT)
        var decoded_card2 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(Cards_bytes, 0, Cards_bytes.size)

    }.addOnFailureListener{exception ->
        Toast.makeText(this,"Failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
```

Thanks for the help!

I tried to define the decoded_card2 variable as Bitmap?=null before the get function, but the program does not detect this change when it exits the function, its value remains null.

Comment: Most likely it's not a matter of *where* you access the variable, but *when* you access it. Data is loaded from Firestore asynchronously, and your code continues to execute while that is going on. Unless you synchronize the asynchronous call with your other code, the other code likely accesses the variable before the data has been loaded and assigned to it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-or-launches-a-coroutine-return-an-empty-o and more questions I linked.

Comment: I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/CloudFirestore/tree/master).